# How do I get the entity ID from a view row and pass it along to the item list template?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I have a view which returns rows of entities. Each entity has several multi-value fields.

The structure is kinda like this:

- Field 1:

  - Item A
  - Item B
  - Item C
  - ...
  - Item H
- Field 2:

  - Item A
  - Item B
  - Item C

Field 2 holds values that are related to Field 1 Item B.
When displaying Field 1 in the view results I'd like to be able to display them like:

Field 1:
Item A, Item B (Field 2 Item A, Field 2 Item B), Item C, Item D

Because its a multi value field Views is using the item_list template. My plan was that I would adds some conditionals to this template so that if Field 1 Item B was to be shown, I would use Twig Tweak to add the values from Field 2 inline to it. The only problem is that to do that I need the row's entity ID. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to pass this information into the item_list template. This template seems completely removed from the view and doesn't have a way to reference it.

I've been trying various functions in my theme file to get the result row NID and pass it along as a variable into the list_item template, but have had nothing but failure. I've figured out how to get a custom variable into the item_list template preprocess_item_list, but I can't figure out how to get the row NID into this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably easiest to create a custom Field Formatter for Field 1 rather than try to do this stuff in preprocesses / twig.

Answer (score 0):

Add the node id as a hidden field to the view, then inside the templates {% for item in items %} you should be able to reference it as item.content['#node'].0.nid|raw but you may need to kint item.content to find out the actual value.

Comment: It actually is a field in the view, but I can't access it from the list item template.

Comment: I ended up doing it in a more hackie way. I found I could get what I want using the non-Views view display by replacing the output in the template of the Views field with a Twig Tweak field function essentially bypassing the Views rendering of the content.